# C++ template variable specialization with GCC 5.4

Tags: c++, templates, gcc

I have come across a strange error in the CI build of a project I'm working in. This only happens on a relatively old OS (Ubuntu 16.04) with a not-so-recent compiler (gcc 5.4.0).

The code causing the error is similar to the following:
(https://godbolt.org/z/MhY6sv)

```
#include <limits>
#include <string>

#define DEFAULT_INIT(x) x{defaultValue<decltype(x)>}

namespace MyProject{

template<typename T>
class Arr1 : public std::array<T, 3>{
public:
    Arr1(T t1, T t2, T t3) : std::array<T, 3>{{t1, t2, t3}}{}
};

template<typename T>
class Arr2 : public std::array<T, 3>{    
    Arr2(T t1, T t2, T t3) : std::array<T, 3>{{t1, t2, t3}}{}
};

namespace{
  template <typename T> constexpr T defaultValue = std::numeric_limits<T>::max();

  template <typename T> const Arr1<T> defaultValue<Arr1<T>> = Arr1<T>{defaultValue<T>, defaultValue<T>, defaultValue<T>};

  template <typename T> const Arr2<T> defaultValue<Arr2<T>> = Arr2<T>{defaultValue<T>, defaultValue<T>, defaultValue<T>};
}

class S {
public:
    S() : DEFAULT_INIT(_arr1), DEFAULT_INIT(_arr2), DEFAULT_INIT(_n) {}
    S(unsigned int n) : DEFAULT_INIT(_arr1), DEFAULT_INIT(_arr2), _n{n} {}

private:
    Arr1<unsigned int> _arr1;
    Arr1<float> _arr2;
    unsigned int _n;
};
}

int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

which results in an assembler error

```
/tmp/ccWrYvQ2.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccWrYvQ2.s:110: Error: symbol `_ZN9MyProject12_GLOBAL__N_1L12defaultValueE' is already defined
```

Playing around with compiler explorer (and given that other CI builds with more recent versions of gcc compile without problems) I've seen that this happens only for gcc < 6.2 and that it is due to the compiler generating the same symbol for both `defaultValue<Arr1<T>>` and `defaultValue<Arr2<T>>`.

Since in this project we still want to support (for now) the faulty OS with its default compiler, is there any workaround to get this to properly work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We may minimize the OP's [overly bloated example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) into:

```
template <typename T> struct A {};

template <typename T> const T defaultValue = 0;
template <typename T> const A<T> defaultValue<A<T>> = A<T>{};

struct S {
    S() : a1{defaultValue<decltype(a1)>},
          a2{defaultValue<decltype(a2)>} {}
    A<char> a1;
    A<int> a2;
};

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

and get the same symbol collision error on most GCC versions prior to GCC 6.2 (it successfully compiles on e.g. GCC 5.3 but has regressed in GCC 5.4).

This is GCC bug

- [Bug 71875 - [5 Regression] template specialization compile error](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=71875),

where the root cause is [Bug 69515 - partial specialization of variable templates is broken](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=69515), both of which were resolved as of GCC 6.2.

> Since in this project we still want to support (for now) the faulty OS with its default compiler, is there any workaround to get this to properly work?

If you want to stick with the older GCC compiler version, you will need to avoid using partial specialization of variable templates and instead e.g. wrap the value in a meta-function:

```
template <typename T> struct A {};

template <typename T>
struct default_value {
    static const T value = 0;  
};

template <typename T>
struct default_value<A<T>> {
    static const A<T> value;  
};

template <typename T> 
const A<T> default_value<A<T>>::value = A<T>{};

template <typename T>
const T default_value_v = default_value<T>::value;

struct S {
    S() : a1{default_value_v<decltype(a1)>},
          a2{default_value_v<decltype(a2)>} {}
    A<char> a1;
    A<int> a2;
};

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks like a viable option. Sorry for the bloated example, I wanted to stay as faithful as possible to the project code.

Comment: @ValerioFormato Happy to help. No worries, but for future reference, always favour a [_minimal_, complete and verifiable example (mcve)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) over a domain-specific one. SO is generally not interested in any particular projects, and instead strongly recommends to keep questions faithful to their core issues and not the project-specific context in which the core issue appeared for the OP. The rationale is that the question will be easier to grasp and answer, and that the Q&A will be useful for future readers and not only for the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could implement the default values via default constructors, see [here](https://godbolt.org/z/qWqo8M).

Another option is to use just class template specialisations, see [here](https://godbolt.org/z/bveEM7).

Comment: Yes, we could go that way, but we decided not to. In this project users are also supposed to create new classes and data structures. We wanted to provide a "uniform" way of initializing member variables of their classes (we are physicists, not trained developers, we tend to teach "by example". `S` is supposed to be an example class that the user can look at when creating his own). Also, we chose unphysical values here to mean that a field is "invalid", but this might not be the best value for a default constructor (for a `Point` class we might want to default to `(0, 0, 0)`)